# Web2py - SQLFORM.smartgrid: how to retrieve field name and value before submission

Tags: variables, field, edit, web2py

I use smartgrid with 'in the grid' edition of values. To do this, I use the .represent function to add the row_id to the variable name, so that I can retrieve what to update in request.post_vars, where I can retrieve the list of filed name, ids, with the submitted value. 
But I'd like to identify what has been changed by the user in the smartgrid without making an additional I/O in the DB. Is there a global variable where the form fields and initial values are recorded before user change ? Or a function to extract form fields and values before sending it to the view?

Comment: Please show your code, as it is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: db.define_table('cny',Field('f_cny'))
@auth.requires_login()
def tst():
 tb = db.cny
 if len(request.post_vars) >0:
  d = {}
  for k,v in request.post_vars.iteritems():
   (f,sep,r) = k.partition('_r_')
   if r:
    d[r][f] = v
  for r in d:
   db(tb.id==r).update(**d[r])
 tb.f_cny.represent=lambda v,r:string_widget(tb.f_cny, v, **{'_name':'f_cny_r_%s' % r.id})
 f = SQLFORM.smartgrid(tb,linked_tables=[],selectable=(lambda ids:redirect(URL(request.controller,request.function,args=request.args))))
 return dict(f=f)

Comment: Please put the code in the question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.define_table('cny',Field('f_cny')) 
def tst(): 
    tb = db.cny
    if len(request.post_vars) >0: 
        d = {} 
        for k,v in request.post_vars.iteritems(): 
            (f,sep,r) = k.partition('_r_') 
            if r:
                if not r in d:
                    d[r] = {}
                d[r][f] = v #should only be done if d[r][f] was changed!!!
                for r in d:
                    if len(d[r]): 
                        db(tb.id==r).update(**d[r]) 
    tb.f_cny.represent=lambda v,r:string_widget(tb.f_cny, v, **{'_name':'f_cny_r_%s' % r.id}) 
    f = SQLFORM.smartgrid(tb,
                          linked_tables=[],
                          selectable=(lambda ids:redirect(URL(request.controller,request.function,args=request.args))))
    return dict(f=f)
```

Comment: Some Explanation with answer will help other to understand easy way dude